# Identify this bathroom light switch?

Tags: electrical, lighting, bathroom, switch

I'd like help identifying the light timer switch on the right hand side of this panel. It is being used in an apartment on the west coast of the USA.

[image: timer switch]

It's unclear if it is a motion sensor or just a timer. One must physically turn the lights on by hitting the button on the top. There does not appear to be a PIR window (the grill and lower portion both appear to be hard opaque plastic).

We'd like a maker/model number so we can figure out how to properly use it (without pulling the facade off).

The switch on the left is of course a combined light/fan switch.

Comment: What do the labels say on the side and back of the unit?

Comment: As I note, it's not my property so I don't feel that I should take the facade off. Otherwise I would have.

Comment: (Sorry, misread.)

Comment: You've said it turns on manually... Does it turn off automatically after a span of time without anyone in the room?

Comment: It turns off by itself after a period of time with no one in the room. So it acts like a PIR except it doesn't turn on by itself when someone enters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a [Wattstopper PW-301-LA Motion Sensor, Passive Infrared Wall Switch](http://www.legrand.us/wattstopper/sensors/optional-neutral-occupancy-sensors/pw-301.aspx).

You reprogram it for auto-on by flipping dipswitches underneath the power button. The PIR window is hidden in the lower third panel. The default is manual-on (PIR off) per CA electrical efficiency requirements so I don't think I'll change it.

The manual is on the manufacturer website.

[image: wattpower]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what brand/model this timer and sensor is, but I can almost guarantee that is a sensor. Whoever installed it looks like they installed it upside down though. If it only works as a switch as you said, maybe try holding down the button for 5-8 seconds and see if it changes modes. Then it may turn into a proper sensor.